# Making an alert view pop up when a trigger condition is reached

Tags: ios, xcode4, uialertview, xcode4.3, alert

I am trying to make a game on Xcode and I would like an alert message to pop up when the user reaches a certain score, say 100 points. I've got the code to make an alert pop up when the view loads up. But what I would like is for the alert message to only show when the player gets to a certain score.

The game's scoring works like this: every time the player clicks/taps a button, he gets one point, so he gets 100 points after tapping 100 times.

Here's the code to make the alert message pop up when the view loads up:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tile" message:@"This is the message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button action call method to show alert when point reaches 100.

For example

```
- (void) buttonAction {
    point++;
    if(point == 100)
      [self showAlert];
}

- (void) showAlert {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                          initWithTitle:@"Tile"
                          message:@"This is the message" 
                          delegate:nil 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

       [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

Comment: hi just copied that straight in the .m but i got like 5 errors is it possible you can tell me how to insert it thanks

Comment: i think i might have sorted the other error it just comes up with 1 error now  [alert release]; ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'??

Comment: also... 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode ?? thats 2 errors just for the release and by the way i really appreciate this buddy

Comment: Since you are using arc release are written by compiler automatically.So you dont want to write releases manually.
Just comment out  [alert release]; , thanks and dont forget to upvote it :).

Comment: ALso if you are planning to work/develop games for iPhone/iPads, I suggest you to use Cocos2d.

Comment: ok i deleted the release and all is ok but now how do i had that to my button

Comment: @Arshad Do you known how i can add it to the button so when i have click it a 100 times it shows the alert message

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't put your alert in the viewDidLoad, instead put it in a method call whatever name.
2. In your button action event handler, when the count reaches 100, call the method whatever name above to show the alert.